# Availability of WebHID/WebUSB APIs on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, webusb, webhid

I know WebHID/WebUSB are generally available in Google Chrome (https://caniuse.com/webhid and https://caniuse.com/?search=webusb) but are these APIs available also on the iOS version of Google Chrome? I was getting reports from users not being able to connect their devices on iOS (iPad) but unfortunately, I don't have a device to test it on and I didn't find any mentions of it online. Can anybody confirm whether these APIs are available in the iOS version of Chrome?

Comment: It is very unlikely since it isn't supported in Safari on iOS and Chrome is just a wrapper around iOS's WebKit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebUSB and WebHID are not available in any browser on iOS.

I don't believe it would be possible for any browser to implement them because iOS doesn't provide the APIs a native application like a web browser needs to implement them. The necessary APIs are only part of the macOS SDK.

Comment: Luckily DriverKit now supports iPad OS 16+ on AppleSilicon https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/creating_drivers_for_ipados #theHopeIsBack

Comment: The implementations of these APIs on macOS do not use DriverKit. While the fact that iPadOS supports it now is encouraging I'm not sure that it would work, at least not in a generic way.